# Output state is undefined

Tags: level-translation

I am using [SN74LVC1T45](https://www.ti.com/general/docs/suppproductinfo.tsp?distId=10&gotoUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ti.com%2Flit%2Fgpn%2Fsn74lvc1t45) for level translation of 1.8V to 5V. What is the output state when the input is floating/disconnected? Is it high, low or undefined ?

I need output to be to at defined state while the input is floating.

Is it possible to achieve my requirement using SN74LVC1T45?

Comment: Useful search terms: pullup/pulldown resistors.

Comment: Don't leave digital inputs floating or disconnected. Use a pullup or pulldown resistor.

Answer (score 3):

According to the introduction of the datasheet:

> The input circuitry is always active on both
> A and B ports and must have a logic HIGH or LOW
> level applied to prevent excess ICC and ICCZ.

So you have to ensure that the input is never floating : for this, you should add a pull-up or pull down resistor to input (ie resistor between input and Vcc_in or ground)

For the value of the resistors, you can use something around 10k (except if whatever drives the input can deliver less than 1mA, then you might consider a bigger value).

Comment: When you say that the input is hi-Z, then the output is hi-Z, are you saying that based off the table titled "Table 3. SYSTEM-1 and SYSTEM-2 Data Transmission"? I don't think that's what the table is saying. I think the table is describing what the behavior of "System-1" and "System-2" in the suggested application needs to be, not what the behavior of the SN74LVC1T45 is.

Comment: Thanks, indeed it seems to be only for the application, not for the device itself. I will edit my post accordingly